# How to dump/append all the values of a dict into a list if key is a tuple?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, tuples

I have a dict as follows with unit names and testnames in a list:

```
dictA = {('unit1', 'test1'): 10,  ('unit2', 'test1'): 78,  ('unit2', 'test2'): 2, ('unit1', 'test2'): 45}  
units = ['unit1', 'unit2']  
testnames = ['test1','test2']
```

How do we append all values of say test1 into a list?
i.e.

```
temp = [10,78] # test1 values
temp2 = [2,45] # test2 values
```

Comment: you keep posting similar questions with the same data. Are you trying to learn from the answers?

Comment: @eumiro: hi, im data crunching a huge chunk of data to yield the stats. looking into different/best possible ways to arrange the  them into a data structure. some suggest: {(tuple),value} is best but some say {x:{y:z}} form is better. looking at and of course learning all possible methods by comparing to my 'multi-liner' codes. :) plz bare! thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're asking about [list comprehensions](http://www.python.org/doc//current/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
[v for k,v in dictA.iteritems() if k[1] == 'test1']
```

Will give you:

```
[10, 78]
```

Similarly:

```
>>> [v for k,v in dictA.iteritems() if k[1] == 'test2']
[2, 45]
```

Now, where the `key` is a tuple, we referenced the element in the `if`-clause.

Answer (score 1):

`temp = [ j for i, j in dictA.iteritems() if "test1" in i ]`

Answer (score 1):

I would get dictA into a for that is dictionaries of dictionaries - either by conversion or better by constructing it in this form

```
dictA = {'unit1':{'test1': 10, 'test2': 2}, 'unit2': {'test1': 78, 'test2': 45}}
```

Then

```
temp = [dictA[x]['test1'] for x in units] 
temp2 = [dictA[x]['test2'] for x in units]
```

Comment: helpful. thanks. earlier i had the dict in that form, but changed to my form due to performing operation between values in dicts would be easier in my form. :)